# Verbosity is killing IPython Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, keras

I am currently working with `keras` in an IPython 3 notebook, however, if I use the `verbosity` option of the `fit_generator()` function, the notebook starts to freeze. I am not sure why this is the case. I have to wait a considerable amount of time and maybe after a while it's coming back but most of the time I simply kill it. For now I don't use it at all but I'd loke to. Any idea what the problem could be?

Example using `verbosity=1`:

```py
model.fit_generator(generator=batch_generator(train, seed=42),
                    samples_per_epoch=train.shape[0],
                    nb_epoch=1,
                    callbacks=[tbCallback, TestCallback((test, test))],
                    verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been pointed out before: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/5165

As far as I can tell, the issue is with data accumulation in iPython, so it's pretty much unavoidable if you are running many epochs and long epochs.

Either decrease the update rate in `keras/utils/generic_utils.py`, or set `verbosity=0`

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that - let's see if they change that in the future.